# Importing txt without header

Tags: stata

I did the following

```
import delimited using "input.txt", delimiters("\t")
```

But input.txt does not have a header.

I could see that the first row of the data just becomes a header.

Numbers become header like v1, v2.. , and characters become header like a,y,..

If data look like

```
2014 11 A 03 
2014 11 B 06
```

then the data loaded in Stata is

```
header:    v1  v2 a v4 
1st row:  2014 11 B 06
```

What can I do to just add an arbitrary header that goes "v1, v2, v3.." without omitting the first row of input.txt?

Comment: Try `infile v1 v2 str1 v3 v4  using input.txt, clear`  (There will be a solution in terms of `import delimited`, but I can't experiment right now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stata 13 [manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dimportdelimited.pdf) indicates that the option you want is `varnames`

```
import delimited using "input.txt", delimiters("\t") varnames(nonames)
```